# Write a bash loop using loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops

How to write a bash script, if enter empty value "", or other value than 1 and 2 will not end the script, and will let user to renter 1 or 2. Basely if user type wrong, will let user to renter.

```
    echo Press 1 for services and 2 for chkconfig?
    echo -n "Please input yes or no: "
    read ANS
if [ $ANS != "" ];

if [ $ANS == 1 ];
then
   service vsftpd status
elif [ $ANS == 2 ];
then
 service vsftpd status
else
echo please input 1 oe 2

fi
~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while true
do
    echo -n "Enter 1 for status, 2 for chkconfig, or q to quit: "
    read ANS
    if [ "$ANS" = q ]
    then
       break
    elif [ "$ANS" = 1 ]
    then
       service vsftpd status
       break
    elif [ "$ANS" = 2 ]
    then
       service vsftpd chkconfig
       break
    else
       echo "Invalid input.  Try again."
    fi
done
```

Notes:

- To allow the use to reenter an answer if he failed to enter a proper answer the first time, the code is placed in a `while` loop.  When a satisfactory answer is given, the `break` command is used to exit the loop.  Lacking a satisfactory answer, the loop repeats until one is entered.
- I added a "quit" option as this is something that users will generally insist on.
- Inside `[` style tests, the symbol for equality is `=`.  Some shells will accept `==` here but others will choke on it.  On the other hand, if `[[` style tests are used (requires bash), then `==` is the correct symbol for equality.
- In `[` style tests, it is important to put shell variables in double-quotes.  Thus, replace `[ $ANS = 1 ]` with `[ "$ANS" = 1 ]`.  Otherwise, if the user type nothing but enter, then `ANS` would be empty and script would fail with an error.  With `[[` style tests, the quotes are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This will keep asking until you enter a "1" or a "2".

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ]; 
do
echo Please enter 1 or 2:
read ANS;
    if [ "$ANS" = "1" ]; then echo You entered 1!; break; fi
    if [ "$ANS" = "2" ]; then echo You entered 2!; break; fi
done
```